# OPTIMIZAR CODIGO SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

Recien empiezo en esto de PLSQL y me gustaría hacerles una consulta:

Tengo este codigo SQL que se repite varias veces.

```
UPDATE bdiv10_sgd_tramo
 SET unidad_cons3 = 'N2L84'
 WHERE codigo IN (
                  SELECT DISTINCT TR.CODIGO FROM
--Primer Select
                  (SELECT codigo FROM bdiv10_sgd_tramo WHERE bdi_job=0
                    AND ten_nom = 3
                    AND cant_conduc in(1,2,3)
                    AND tip_cond_c1 in(20,43,46)
                    AND tipo_tramo = 'A') TR,
--Segundo Select
                  (SELECT c.CODIGO_ENTIDAD FROM
                      (SELECT codigo FROM BDIV10_HIST_ESTADOS_TRABAJOS) a,
                      (SELECT codigo,FECHA_APROB,estado FROM BDIV10_HISTORICO_TRABAJOS) b,
                      (SELECT CODIGO_TRABAJO,CLASS_ID,ACCION,CODIGO_ENTIDAD FROM bdiv10_historico_entidades) c
                    WHERE b.estado = 4
                    AND SUBSTR(a.codigo,5,20) = b.codigo
                    AND C.CODIGO_TRABAJO = b.codigo
                    AND b.codigo = c.codigo_trabajo
                    AND B.FECHA_APROB >= 20240101
                    AND C.CLASS_ID IN (1084)
                    AND C.ACCION='ALTA') APROB

                    WHERE APROB.CODIGO_ENTIDAD=TR.CODIGO);
commit;
```

Los valores del WHERE del primer select varian, sin embargo el segundo select sí es igual siempre, debido a que no cuento con permisos en la base de datos no puedo crear procesos ni funciones ni nada por el estilo.

Lo que he intentado hasta ahora es esto:

```
DECLARE
  COD bdiv10_sgd_apoyo.codigo%TYPE;
  
  TYPE ResultRecord IS RECORD (CODIGO bdiv10_sgd_apoyo.codigo%TYPE);
  TYPE ResultArray IS TABLE OF ResultRecord;
  results ResultArray;
  
  CURSOR var_cursor IS SELECT DISTINCT MT.codigo/*,MT.mat_ap,MT.altura,MT.peso,MT.estructura015*/ FROM
                    (SELECT codigo,mat_ap,altura,peso,estructura015 FROM bdiv10_sgd_apoyo WHERE onis_stat='0' AND onis_ver NOT LIKE '%.%' AND tipo_apoyo IN ('MT','MT-BT')) MT,
                    (SELECT c.CODIGO_ENTIDAD FROM
                        (SELECT codigo FROM BDIV10_HIST_ESTADOS_TRABAJOS) a,
                        (SELECT codigo,FECHA_APROB,estado FROM BDIV10_HISTORICO_TRABAJOS) b,
                        (SELECT CODIGO_TRABAJO,CLASS_ID,ACCION,CODIGO_ENTIDAD FROM bdiv10_historico_entidades) c
                      WHERE b.estado = 4 AND SUBSTR(a.codigo,5,20) = b.codigo AND C.CODIGO_TRABAJO = b.codigo AND b.codigo = c.codigo_trabajo 
                      AND C.ACCION='ALTA' 
                      AND C.CLASS_ID IN (3001)
                      AND B.FECHA_APROB >= 20240101)
                      APROB WHERE APROB.CODIGO_ENTIDAD=MT.CODIGO;
BEGIN
    OPEN var_cursor;
     FETCH var_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO results;
    CLOSE var_cursor;
END;
```

pero no he podido avanzar de allí, podrían guiarme al respecto?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Guiarte en que sentido?? sin la base de datos es dificil saber que tipo de optimizaciones se pueden hacer... mas que tirar ideas al aire...

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esta no sea la optimización que necesites, pero es una simplificación de tu código original. Elimina la necesidad de leer dos veces una tabla y reduce la cantidad de código permitiendo que el motor encuentre el plan óptimo para tu consulta en vez de tratar de preoptimizar con subconsultas.

```
UPDATE bdiv10_sgd_tramo
  SET unidad_cons3 = 'N2L84'
WHERE bdi_job     = 0
AND   ten_nom     = 3
AND   cant_conduc IN( 1, 2, 3)
AND   tip_cond_c1 IN( 20, 43, 46)
AND   tipo_tramo  = 'A'
AND   codigo IN (
                    SELECT he.CODIGO_ENTIDAD 
                    FROM BDIV10_HIST_ESTADOS_TRABAJOS het
                    JOIN BDIV10_HISTORICO_TRABAJOS    ht  ON SUBSTR(het.codigo,5,20) = ht.codigo
                    JOIN BDIV10_HISTORICO_ENTIDADES   he  ON ht.codigo = he.codigo_trabajo
                    WHERE ht.estado      = 4
                    AND   ht.FECHA_APROB >= 20240101
                    AND   he.CLASS_ID    IN (1084)
                    AND   he.ACCION      ='ALTA');
commit;
```